# Using a Lambda Function to Convert a Column thats a list to a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out a way to convert a column in a data frame that is currently a list to a set.

#Converting column from a list to a set

df['Column2']=s.apply(lambda x: [x])

The Error I am getting is mentioned below

NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: Why do you think `[x]` would convert a `list` into a `set`?

Comment: In any case, `s` is indeed not defined -- at least not in the code you show us, you haven't provided a [mcve]. Why did you *expect* `s` to be defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the goal is to convert one column of my table( imported from a csv) from a list to a set. Ultimate goal of this post is to search this column using a user input. 


#ConvertCSVtoTable
df = pd.read_csv("Panel_Picker.csv")
print(df)

#AskUserWhatAntibodiesAreNeeded
my_set = set(input('Enter Antibodies that are Comma Separated : ').split(','))

print(my_set)
#Converting Antibodies column from a list to a set

df['Antibodies'] = df['Antibodies'].apply(lambda x: {x})

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this helps. It uses `lambda` to go over the column and set the type of each of them to a set.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[1,2,3],'Column2':[4,5,6]})
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x: {x})
```

Comment: this is almost certainly *not* what the OP wants, given that they state that the elements are lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what does the op want I thought he wanted to make the values into sets???